# trying to make a score system

Tags: batch-file, dll

well I'm trying as title say> to make a score system. ive been googling. and tried different things but I simply cant get it to work
i want it to work like this: you type in your name. then it checks if the dll file exist in the players folder. if it doesn't, it will make it. and if it does. it will just overwrite.

if it does exist however. it will first retrieve the existing score value from the dll file.
then I want it to just add in 1 point  by every time
you come to the :addscore section.
and each time it passes :addscore. this new value will then be saved to the file (replaced) and then this continues :P

heres the code I got so far: and as u can see. it does not retrieve the score from the file. and neither it will set the score value any higher than 1... any tips?

```
@echo off
:: User check
:usercheck
set /p usrn=Username:
set score=0
if exist "D:\General_menus\users\%usrn%\playerdb.dll" (
    for /f %%A in ("D:\General_menus\users\%usrn%\playerdb.dll") do set score=%%A
    echo Welcome back %usrn%
    goto addscore
    ) else (
    echo Hello new player %usrn%
    set score=0
    )
    pause>nul
:: user check end
::====================================================
::add score
:addscore
set /a score+=1
echo your score is %score%
echo saving data
goto scorecheck
::add score end
::===================================================
:scorecheck
echo %score%
echo %score% > "\General_menus\users\%usrn%\playerdb.dll"
pause>nul
goto usercheck
```

Comment: Why do you call a text file with your score in it .dll ? That's confusing.

Comment: because the dll is going to be used as a string list (sort of) it stores values and retrieves them. (or well more plain text really). its for later use of abigger script im building. why i want to do that doesnt reeally matter. (i prefere using dll's for storage purpouses.)

Comment: The approach can work, I guess. Of course, the player can easily edit their own score. Don't know if that is a problem. But I have to question wanting to implement this as a batch-file. Why not use a more powerful programming language? Presumably the whole project is bigger than just this one function.

Comment: Because im doing this for educational purposes and because it's fun and I think this is a good idea to learn a lot. Plus I really want to make a batch game xD. However. I believe I can put on some encryption onto the files. So I don't think that would be a problem. But if u got any other suggestions. Then I'm listening ^^

Comment: Get rid of the quotes around the file name in the `for /f` loop.

Comment: Do u mean the bunny ears?

Comment: http://imgur.com/7lWSm6d

Comment: Add "usebackq" option to this FOR command: `for /f "usebackq" %%A in ("D:\General...`. See `HELP FOR` for further details.

Comment: All right thanks. I will try it out ^^

Comment: it worked man ! THANKS <3333

Comment: i checked the "usebackq" .. why would i use that? does it work with the dll so i etc can make a variable string and it will get it out from the dll? (what purpouse does usebackq serve to me in this context)?

Comment: @KevinKyoNightwolf: if you have a path or filename with spaces, you _have_ to use the quotes. Use `usebackq" to tell `for` not to treat it as as string (as it would normally) but as a filename in quotes.

Comment: ahhh :D thanks man :D

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by: -@Thilo
fix: remove the bunny ears from line:" `for /f %%A in ("D:\General_menus\users\%usrn%\playerdb.dll") do set score=%%A`"